# Object attributes not updating in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am trying to update my object body field through a protected method in the background, using sidekiq:

```
class BodyWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(offer_id)
    offer = Offer.find(offer_id)

    remove_html(offer)
    offer.publish!
  end

    protected

      def remove_html(offer)
        offer.body = ''
        offer.save
      end
```

According to the console there are no mistakes, however the offer.body stays the same. Any advice?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I am having a similar issue and I have no Idea what to do.

Answer (score 2):

> According to the console there are no mistakes

Are you checking from console by using something like

```
BodyWorker.perform_async(offer.id)
```

and then wondering why your `offer` is not updated? It's another instance of `Offer` that was updated and saved. And yours won't magically pull latest state from the DB. Refresh it manually by using something like

```
offer.reload
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, however I still cannot save any changes using methods in my worker.

Comment: Well, too bad? My crystal ball is displaying a lot of static today. (hint: http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

> protected
>
> ```
>  def remove_html(offer)
>    offer.body = ''
>   offer.save
>  end
> ```

Try

```
offer.save!
```